# How to capture order line items from order made on shopware 6, using order_line_item.repository

Tags: php, symfony, repository, shopware

Hello I am trying to filter out the list of items coming through an order a customer makes

`services :   <argument type="service" id="order_line_item.repository"/>`

in my class :

`use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;`

`private readonly EntityRepository $orderLineItemRepository;`

construct and so on.

now based on my research I am trying to filter based on the version id of the order

`$event->getOrder()->getOrderCustomer()->getVersionId()`

`$orderLine = $this->orderLineItemRepository`
    ``` ->search(new Criteria([$event->getOrder()->getOrderCustomer()->getVersionId()]), ``$event->getContext()) ```
 `->first();`

but it keeps returning blank, I need it to return the list of items in the order that was submitted by the user, so I can then use in a for each loop like this :

`$items = $order->getLineItems();`

```
  foreach ($items as $product) {
            $orderRow = [
                "sku" => $product->getProduct()->getProductNumber(),
              
            
            ];
        }
```

Please help, what would be the right method of getting the items out. Im working with shopware 6.5. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, I was able to achieve this by first accessing the $eveny dataset and getting order

```
 $order = $event->getOrder();
```

then inside order I accessed order line items

```
 $lineItems = $order->getLineItems();
```

I then of course used a for each loop to get out all elements or fields in this $ lineItems